# Load JSON data into BigQuery table

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load simple JSON data into BigQuery table the following way:

```bash
$ bq load \
    --apilog \
    --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    my_dataset.my_table \
    ./input.json ./schema.json
```

but get the following error message:

```
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_xxxx_xxx ... (3s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my_project_id:bqjob_xxxx_xxx': CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.
Failure details:
- file-00000000: Error detected while parsing row starting at
position: 0. Error: Data between close double quote (") and field
separator.
```

It complains about some CSV error, but I'm trying to load JSON (`--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`)

My `input.json` contains this data:

```json
{"domain":"stackoverflow.com","key":"hello","value":"world"}
```

My `schema.json` is the following:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "domain",
        "type": "string",
        "mode": "nullable"
    },
    {
        "name": "key",
        "type": "string",
        "mode": "nullable"
    },
    {
        "name": "value",
        "type": "string",
        "mode": "nullable"
    }
]
```

`bq` version 2.0.25:

```
$ gcloud version | grep ^bq
bq 2.0.25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the flag `apilog` expects a string as input. This command should work for you:

```
bq load \
    --apilog '' \
    --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    my_dataset.my_table \
    ./input.json ./schema.json
```

Empty string sends output to `stdout`. If you want to save the log to a local file then you can just send a non-empty string, such as `--apilog 'localfile_name'`.

Answer (score 2):

BQ command says:

```
USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]
```

As you see there are **global_flags** and **command_flags**

For the **global_flags** that have values you need to use the equal sign:

```
--flag=value
```

The **command_flags** are either boolean:

```
--[no]replace
```

Or they take arguments that must follow the flag:

```
--source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
```

Also do not mix global and command flags: apilog is a global flag.
I would rewrite your command into:

```
$ bq --apilog load \
    --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    my_dataset.my_table \
    ./input.json ./schema.json
```

Comment: It's better to use `bq --apilog - load …` or `bq --apilog '' load …` because without parameter `--apilog` uses `load` as its parameter.